# iOS Adding a button to JWplayer 7 control bar to control

Tags: ios, sdk, jwplayer

I am able to change color of the control bar by editting the "http://p.jwpcdn.com/iOS/Skins/nature01/nature01.css".  However, I would like to add a button in control bar in full screen mode with iOS sdk. Any method I can do it ?

```
config.image = @"/image.jpg";           //title image
config.title = @"JWPlayer Demo";        // video title
config.controls = YES;  //default       //show/hide controls
config.repeat = NO;   //default     //repeat after completion
config.premiumSkin = JWPremiumSkinRoundster;    //JW premium skin
config.cssSkin = @"http://p.jwpcdn.com/iOS/Skins/nature01/nature01.css
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ob6jR.png)

Comment: its better to write code what you tried.

Comment: Welcome to posting on Stackoverflow! Please follow these guidelines: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) & provide the code as @MRizwan33 requested...Cheers.

Comment: The link is not working!